# Change font of MATLAB dialogue

Tags: matlab, dialog, font-size, tex

I am trying to change the font size of the message text in a `questdlg`. I have been able to get some TeX to work (subscript, greek letters), but I can't figure out how to change the font. Here's what I've tried:

```
test_str = '\fontsize{10}{12}\selectfont Words go here';
options.Default = 'yes';
options.Interpreter = 'tex';

questdlg(test_str,'title','yes','no',options)
```

And I get the warning message:

```
Warning: Error updating Text.

 String must have valid interpreter syntax:
\fontsize{10}{12}\selectfont Words go here

> In defaulterrorcallback (line 12)
  In questdlg (line 314)
```

I am pretty certain that the text I am using is valid TeX syntax, but I don't know why it's not working. Is there something I'm missing, or is there a list of supported features for this particular interpreter?

Comment: What's the `{12}\selectfont` part all about?

Comment: @KyleH that is the correct way to set the font size to an arbitrary value in LaTeX: the first argument (10) is the font size, the second (12) is the baseline skip. With `\fontsize` you only define the size of the next used font, so you have to enable it with `\selectfont`.

Comment: @hbaderts Got it - thanks!  I wasn't sure what he was trying to accomplish, since `'test_str = '\fontsize{10} Words go here'` is all that's needed for Tex interpretation.  Didn't realize the goal was more complex formatting.

Comment: @KyleH I wasn't necessarily going for the more complex formatting, so your solution would also be a valid answer.

Comment: @DavidK I guess now you've got a number of options to choose from :)

Comment: You're right @Kyle, I wasn't aware of that. [Here](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_plots/greek-letters-and-special-characters-in-graph-text.html#bux4rpf) is a list of markup options for the `tex` option. I guess that would be the simpler way... Do you want to add an answer about this, Kyle?

Comment: @hbaderts That link is *exactly* what I need!

Comment: Or maybe [this link](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/text-properties.html), which is specifically on the different interpreters and possibilities.

Comment: @hbaderts  Sure, I can add it for the record.  But being able to use Latex certainly does offer more options for formatting than Tex does. I wonder if there's a reason that Latex support isn't documented for `questdlg`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually, the `\fontsize` command is not TeX - it is LaTeX! So, change the interpreter from `tex` to `latex`, and it works:

```
test_str = 'Normal size, \fontsize{18}{24}\selectfont other size';
options.Default = 'yes';
options.Interpreter = 'latex';

questdlg(test_str,'title','yes','no',options)
```

[image: resulting dialog box]

Comment: Thanks, this works! I was thrown off because the [`questdlg` doc page](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/questdlg.html) says that the only options are `none` and `tex`, but not `latex`. Do you have any idea if this is deprecated functionality?

Comment: Hm, good point - I didn't even check for that... Usually, both (`tex` or `latex`) are available, so I don't think it is deprecated - but you cannot know if it isn't officially stated in the docs.

Answer (score 2):

The proper Tex syntax for the display string would simply be

```
'test_str = '\fontsize{10} Words go here';
```

The full list of available Tex markup options can be found on [this page](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_plots/greek-letters-and-special-characters-in-graph-text.html#bux4rpf).